# Forget docker container linux password. How do I reset it?

Tags: linux, docker

[image]

I forget this container ubuntu password. Is there any method to change it.

Comment: i want install some package .like this developer@78b69db98c73:/$ sudo apt install net-tools
bash: sudo: command not found

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when i try to install package  i get permissioin denied error.apt-get install apache2
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Comment: The "are you root" is the giveaway. The command only works for root user, i.e. you have to sudo apt-get... which doesn't work either because "command not found". To resolve that one check that your normal user's path actually has a reference to where sudo is. Where to find sudo, try command "which sudo". In general installations with apt, dpkg, aptitude etc can only be done sudoed. But how exactly is this related to your question? If you have a separate issue you should ask a separate question. Also it's better to update your question with new info than answer in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can log into the Docker container using the root user (ID = 0)
instead of the provided default user when you use the `-u` option:

```
docker exec -u 0 -it mycontainer bash
docker container exec -u 0 -it mycontainer bash
```

See
[Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/).

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35485346/165358)

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem .